# Converting string date to date

Tags: java, date, datetime

How would I convert a String date in the form of 24/04/2012 to a date variable in the format of 24-Apr-12, which can later be passed into my Oracle database.

I have tried this but it says the string date is unparsable:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date newDate = (Date) format.parse(date);
```

Comment: Since it hasn't been said before... look into Joda-Time if you're going to be handling Dates in Java. The API is much, much cleaner then the original Date packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this backwards:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date newDate = format.parse(date);

DateFormat formatOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String output = formatOutput.format(newDate);
```

But if what you are doing is passing the date to Oracle, you should really use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing parsing and formatting, try this:

```
String old_date = "24/04/2012";

DateFormat old_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date newDate = (Date) old_format.parse(old_date);

DateFormat new_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String date = new_format.format(newDate);

System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date format should be "dd/MM/yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
DateTime  newDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using java.sql.Date.

For example:

```
Date newDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

So you can just give an generic sql object for date.

Answer (score 0):

The Date class of Java is quite difficult to use in many cases. I recommend the use of the much better [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) classes:

```
DateTimeFormatter oldFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/mm/yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter newFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
DateTime dateTime = oldFormat.parseDateTime("24/04/2012");
String newDate = newFormat.print(dateTime);
```